# How to mod a WBFS or ISO wii game?

Tags: homebrew, iso, wii, nintendo

Is it possible to modify a wii game (at .iso or .wbfs format) code so that I cange things such as the textures, etc. ?

I know these types of mods exist (for example Super Mario Gravity) but idk if it's possible with just the ISO or WBFS file.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Overall: yes, you can.**

In general, a modification involves the following:

- Extracting the files from the game
- Modifying them
- Running the game with those patched

### Setup

First off you need the ROM of your game. These should be some type of `*.iso` file usually. You can rip this by using a modified Wii with Homebrew and an application like [CleanRip](https://wiibrew.org/wiki/CleanRip).

You also need a *beta* version of the [Dolphin Emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/). Only three non-release versions have the features needed right now.

### Extract the Files

Open the `*.iso` file within Dolphin and ensure it is displayed within the list of the main window. Open the file's "Properties" and then navigate to the "filesystem" tab (the one farthest to the right).

Once in the "filesystem" tab, look for "Data Partition" and then right click on that. Click extract files and choose a location for all the files to go. Keep in mind this might be quite big so put it in a place where it works for you.

### Modifying the Files

Now you have the files you need to modify the game of your choice! If you were making a SMG/SMG2 modification, I'd suggest a tool like [Whitehole][https://github.com/SunakazeKun/Whitehole-Despaghettification]; although, there are much more up-to-date tools so look around first and learn how to use other tools.

Before you're ready to launch, you need to make a `.xml` file stating the files you changed (among other settings). This is where I leave things up to you.

There are some templates [here][https://riivolution.github.io/wiki/Patch_Templates/#All_Games]. These outline what you need in general, you need to figure out what will make this work for you.

### Launching

Go back to Dolphin and find that the original `*.iso` file (files of different type, even from the same game, might not work), then click "Start with Riivolution patches ...", and select your `*.xml` file. With some luck you just launched your modification in Dolphin!

### Note

This isn't a full tutorial, but more so a list of tools and how to access them. If you want to get your hands dirty with modifying a specific game, find the appropriate community and ask questions there. For example [here](https://discord.gg/k7ZKzSDsVq) is a discord server for modifying SMG and SMG2. Stack Overflow might not be the best place for such niche discussions.